# Admob interstitials not clickable on Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2)

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, nexus-5

Do you know of a problem with Admob interstitial Ads not being clickable and therefore not bringing any revenue on Nexus 5 devices?

Facts:

1. It **does not happen with all** interstitial ads - some are clickable, but most **are not**.
2. It happens **both** with the old standalone Google Admob SDK and with the new Google Play Services SDK.
3. It happens on **Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.2**, but maybe it's possible that other devices are affected too.
4. It happens in many programs in the Google Play Store that I've tested with - not only with my application. For example, you can check [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z)
5. It **does not happen** on Galaxy Nexus (Nexus 3), Galaxy S, HTC One.
6. Below is a screenshot of the Ad. The little INFO button in the bottom **is clickable** and opens ok, the X close button is also **working ok**, however clicking on the Ad does not do anything - as if it does not exist or there is something above it.

Do you know of any workaround or possible solution to the problem? 
Thank you!

[image: Admob Interstitial Ad]

--- UPDATE ---

This is the activity declaration:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.middlehut.android.belot.BelotActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Interstitial loading, no special code here:

```
adMobInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
adMobInterstitial.setAdUnitId(AdsConstants.AdMob.INTERSTITIAL_ID);
adMobInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
if(adMobInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
    adMobInterstitial.show();
}
```

Comment: This is my problem too. Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: By the way, I contacted Admob developers in the Google Groups forum about their product and they acted inadequate IMO - they didn't care to find what is the problem or even answer something on my question. I found a way to resolve it for me personally on my device - go to the Google Settings application and reset your Advertising ID. However this is not something that normal users will do, cause they don't care if they can click on the ad in your application.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this issue.
It was due to the flag android:launchMode="singleInstance" on the activity presenting the interstitial.

i think it is an adMob bug, so please check and in case just remove this flag to get interstitial working.

Comment: I had this problem but my activity was not declared 'singleInstance', so I guess it's another case.

Comment: Can you please add your manifest / interstitial init code to your post? Let's try to guess it out!

Comment: I updated the post above with code sample. I think there's nothing special or custom in it. @martino-lessio

Comment: I wasn't talking about the manifest declaration of the ads activity. You have to look into and publish the code of the activity that is presenting your ads.

Comment: again nothing out of the ordinary i think... @martino-lessio

Comment: The only thing you can try is to disable hardware acceleration and requested orientation. try deleting the two rows and see if something changes.

Comment: I cannot test it anymore, because I resolved the issue on my Nexus 5 and I don't have another device that reproduce the issue. As I mentioned above, the issue was resolved by regenerating my Google Advertising Id on the phone. And since than it's ok for my device.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem. There was no problem; it is by design. The ads load if clicked near the middle but not if clicked near the corners. That's why sometimes they seemed to randomly not click through. Took me a while to figure that out.